# Residue theorem for split complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, hyperbolic-geometry, hypercomplex-numbers, split-complex-numbers

One can show that any function on the split-complex numbers which can be represented by a Laurent series is infinitely differentiable, except at the union of several (shifted) hyperbolas of modulus 0 (the "poles") and the derivative of such a function evaluated at a given point (excluding points located on said hyperbolas) is direction-independent. Given this, how would one develop an appropriate residue theorem for these 'meromorphisms' on the split-complex numbers?

As user Peyton has pointed out, the real trouble lies in the inability to integrate along a path which 'contains' such a hyperbolic pole. Is this concept simply not rectifiable?

Comment: What would be the analogous of poles? If we write $z=ae_1+be_2$, with $e_1,e_2$ the diagonal basis, then $\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{a}e_1+\frac{1}{b}e_2$. This goes to infinity near the two lines $a=0$ and $b=0$. We could define what is a loop that goes around the union of those two lines, by traveling near that cross inside one of the quadrants, going to infinity and back again inside the next quadrant etc. but the integral along this is not convergent.

Comment: @Peyton This is precisely the notion which has been giving me trouble. In the complex case, the residue theorem defines the path integral of a closed loop within the domain of a _meromorphic_ function. A meromorphic function is defined in the complex case as being holomorphic everywhere except for a set of _isolated_ points (poles). However, for a split-complex function whose -1'th Laurent coefficient at a value z is nonzero, this function will always go to infinity at the union of two hyperbolas. I feel there must be a more suitable definition of path-integration for hyperbolic geomtery...

Answer (score 4):

I posit that the main idea of contour integrals is Stokes' theorem from multivariable (real) calculus:

$$ \oint_{\partial D} \omega = \int_D \mathrm{d} \omega $$

The residue theorem takes the form it does because of the feature that any function $f$ given by a Laurent series near $a$ can be written in the form
 $$ f(z) = g'(z) + \frac{r}{z-a} $$
where $g$  is also given by a Laurent series near $a$. Thus, for a sufficiently small domain around $a$,

$$ \begin{align} \oint_{\partial D} f(z) \mathrm{d}z &= 
\oint_{\partial D} \left( \mathrm{d} g(z) + \frac{r \, \mathrm{d} z}{z-a} \right) 
\\&= \int_D \mathrm{d}^2 g(z) + r \oint_{\partial D} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z-a} 
\\&= 0 + r (2 \pi i)   \end{align} $$

---

I claim that whatever reasonable can be said about contour integrals in the split-complex numbers is surely also going be just Stokes' theorem.

To get anything resembling the properties of complex numbers, I suspect what you're going to need to do is to look at the complex split complex numbers (I do not know if this has a standard name) — that is, the four-dimensional algebra spanned by $1, i, h, ih$ where $i^2 = -1$ and $h^2 = 1$ — and see how it interacts with four-dimensional differential geometry.

Comment: Interestingly, the algebra you describe is (up to isomorphism) known as the 'bicomplex' numbers. A general bicomplex number has the form (a+bi) + (c+di)j , where i^2 = -1, j^2 = -1, i != j, and ij is not within the span of 1, i, and j. Isomorphism can be established between the bicomplex numbers and your 'complex split-complex numbers' by defining a linear map which sends 1 -> 1 , i -> i , j -> -ih , ij -> h. However, it remains unclear how contour integration in this algebra could produce residues for 'bicomplex' meromorphisms. Perhaps we'd have to integrate along a closed 3d surface...?